# regex capturing number format of 84.1 OR 95

Tags: regex

This is my [regex](https://regex101.com/r/v5j0GG/1)

my data:

```
1   2017-12 A   155749  131033  84.1;
2   2017-12 B   24869   23627   95;
3   2017-12 C   117618  117185  99.6;
```

my regex:

```
(?<serial>\d)\s+(?<date>\d+-\d+)\s+(?<type>\w)\s+(?<attempts>\d+)\s+(?<successfullAttempts>\d+)\s+(?<sr>\d+\.\d)
```

I am having trouble with the `(?<sr>\d+\.\d)` part it does not capture the `95`. It captures the 99.6 and the 84.1.

I was trying to use an OR `|` 
`(?<sr>\d+\.\d|\d+)`

**How do i write this part so I can capture 95?**

Comment: this one should works too: (?<sr>\d+(\.\d)?)

Comment: try `(?<serial>\d)\s+(?<date>\d+-\d+)\s+(?<type>\w)\s+(?<attempts>\d+)\s+(?<successfullAttempts>\d+)\s+(?<sr>\d+(\.\d+)?)` view exampe https://regex101.com/r/uEdG68/1

Comment: Try `(?<sr>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` or `(?<sr>[0-9.]+)`

Answer (score 0):

The data resembles some log file, and that means the data type is known, so you do not have to worry about pre-validation and the pattern can look simpler:

```
(?<serial>\d+)\s+(?<date>\d+-\d+)\s+(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<attempts>\d+)\s+(?<successfullAttempts>\d+)\s+(?<sr>\d[.\d]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QWDgES/2)

The last `(?<sr>\d[.\d]*)` capturing group matches a digit, and then 0+ digits or `.` chars.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could catch any form of number if you just use `(?<sr>.+);` at the end. Of course it captures anything else as well, but on the given example data it works well.